# How can I set limits to the RecalculateAxesScale

Tags: vb.net, charts

How can I make my **chart axis Y** to never go below **50** when using `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).RecalculateAxesScale()`? I want the Y axis to range from `0` to `maximum` value of series (can be from 0 to 1000 and even more), but when the value of series is below 50, the chart should display 0 - 50, and not go below 50.

I have set the properties

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.minimum = 0
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = (theHighestValue.text)
```

And then this is in the code as points are added to the chart

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).RecalculateAxesScale()
```

This works like a charm to be honest, but I just don't want the Y to be below 50.

I know that I could do something like

```
If theHighestValue.text <= 50 Then 
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 50 
Else
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = theHighestValue.text
```

But this will make the Y-axis to be based on the latest points added only, not the highest value in the whole X-axis.

I guess if I some how could do this `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY = 50` in the if statement above, that would solve it - but I can't figure out if there is a way to set that.

I'll be happy to fill in more information if needed.

Comment: First, you should set [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and correct the problems it points out. Otherwise, the variable type mismatches may well make your program very difficult to debug. Second, if you put the "something like" code after `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).RecalculateAxesScale()` but test for `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum` instead of `theHighestValue.text` the then you should get the result that I think you are asking for.